# Memory allocation in R: writing to array slices duplicate entire array

Tags: r

I am having a hard time understanding how to get around "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.5 Gb" with arrays. When I try to write to a slice of an array, R appears to be duplicating the entire array in memory. The only thing I can think of is rewriting my code in C++. But, before I go that route, is there a native way in R to handle this? Here is a minimal working example, which throws the above error. Although if you have more or less than 8 Gb of memory on your machine, then you would need to change the code to account for that. I really appreciate any help.

```
memory.limit(size = 8 * 2^10)
theta_init <- runif(
    n = 100,
    min = 1,
    max = 10
)
theta_init <- theta_init / sum(theta_init)
theta <- array(
    data = theta_init,
    dim = c(10, 10, 1e7)
)
format(
    x = object.size(theta),
    units = "GB"
)
theta[ , , 10] <- theta[, , 9]
```

Comment: There is no other way _with the default data type_ which do a copy on write for the whole (contiguous) vector.  But you could store the data externally (either programmatically, using an external pointer object) or in, say, a Redis in-memory database.  That way you can control updates more finely.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate this @DirkEddelbuettel! I will probably end up using your Rcpp package to solve this problem, so double thanks!

Comment: A cheaper way might be to _not_ use one big vector but a list of several (much) smaller ones.  Then the update only copies only the segment you're writing too.  Otherwise C++ can of course help too with an STL `std::vector<>`  that has a different design and behavior....